# Scipy distribution - Is there a method in Scipy that returns probability (not the probability density) at point?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, beta-distribution

It seems like even if distributions are continuous, I only have an access to the `pdf` method. However, I need the probability itself, say in `[2, 2.0001]`. Is there any method that I can call for a point probability? According to the document https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html, it doesn't seem like to have one.

How do you get the probability at one point, in the most economic way?

Comment: For a continuous distribution, the probability at a point is 0.  See@alexpiers' answer for how to get the probability for an interval.

Comment: You have implicitly identified how to reconcile your desire ("point probability") with the technical detail that @Warren mentiones. You chose a small enough interval to treat as "point-like" for your purposes. Great. But ... don't go *too* small or floating point math issues will rear their ugly heads.

Comment: @warren I'm very well aware that the probability of a point is zero. That's why I asked this question from the beginning -_-

Comment: @dmckee yup, when I said "at point" I meant "point-like".

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `cdf` method.

So the probability of an event occuring in some interval `[a,b]` is just `cdf(b)-cdf(a)`.

Comment: OP will want to note that, for well-behaved distributions, cdf(b) - cdf(a) is going to be pretty well approximated by (b - a) times pdf(a), for b sufficiently close to a.